# array element is not printing

Tags: arrays, c, printf

in the code below printf("%d",cost[i]) is printing garbage value why??
while when i use printf("%d",cost[0]); then it prints right ans

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()

{


  int chef = 0,n,i=0;
  scanf("%d",&n);

 int cost[n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {   fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%d",&cost[i]);

  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++);
  {
      if(cost[i]-5>=chef)
      {
          printf(" %d",cost[i]);
          chef=chef+cost[i];
          chef=chef-(cost[i]-5);
      }
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you notice the semi-colon after your second `for(..);` line? Does your compiler not throw any warnings (about "gaurds")?

Comment: Note also `fflush(stdin);` does nothing. What about to also flush the output writing a newline (`\n`) ?

Comment: Please indent your code properly before posting.

Comment: vote to close for typo (@kabanus explained)

Comment: Your `for` needs a closing brace }

Comment: Please spend a few seconds on formatting your code in a readable way. Bold text or cutting words in half isn't very useful.

Comment: You should use dynamic memory allocation ```malloc()``` instead of  ```int cost[n]```

Comment: thanks to everyone who answered me and sorry for all the inconveniences I'm a newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. missing closing `}` in the second for loop.
2. remove `semicolon ;` at the second for loop end.
3. this code will not work in `C89`. if you need to allocate array that you dont know the size of it in compile time,which means you only knows the size in runtime use `malloc()`.
4. flushing stdin `fflush(stdin)` as per C standard, it is **undefined behavior** . However some compilers allows it. Dont use it if you want to write a portable code.

see below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int chef = 0, n, i=0, *cost=NULL;
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    cost = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if(!cost)
    {
        /*malloc failed*/
        puts("malloc failed");
        abort();
    }
  
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {   
        scanf("%d",&cost[i]);
    }
 
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(cost[i]-5 >= chef)
        {
            printf(" %d",cost[i]);
            chef=chef+cost[i];
            chef=chef-(cost[i]-5);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help

Comment: @Ayu91-my pleasure. :-)